# spark filter (delete) rows based on values from another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a 'big' dataset (`huge_df`) with >20 columns. One of the columns is an `id` field (generated with `pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()`).

Using some criteria I generate a second dataframe (`filter_df`), consisting of `id` values I want to filter later on from `huge_df`.

Currently I am using SQL syntax to do this:

```
filter_df.createOrReplaceTempView('filter_view')
huge_df = huge_df.where('id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM filter_view)')
```

**Question 1:**
Is there a way to do this using Python only, i.e. without the need to register the `TempView`?

**Question 2:**
Is there a completely different way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use JOIN

```
huge_df = huge_df.join(filter_df, huge_df.id == filter_df.id, "left_outer")
                 .where(filter_df.id.isNull())
                 .select([col(c) for c in huge_df.columns]
```

However it will cause expensive shuffle.

Logic is simple: do left join with filter_df on id fields and check if filter_df is null - if it is null, that means that there's no such row in filter_df

Comment: instead of `.select([col(c) for c in huge_df.columns]` you can just say `.select(huge_df.columns)`, no?

Comment: thanks! this helped a lot. I tried to avoid `join`, but it turns out this is way more efficient than `id NOT IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: I think you can use a `left_anti` join instead of `left_outer`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it-

```
# Sample data
hugedf = spark.createDataFrame([[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']],schema=(['k1','v1']))
fildf = spark.createDataFrame([[1,'b'],[3,'c']],schema=(['k2','v2']))


from pyspark.sql.functions import col
hugedf\
.select('k1')\     
.subtract(fildf.select('k2'))\ 
.toDF('d1')\
.join(hugedf,col('d1')==hugedf.k1)\
.drop('d1')\
.show()
```

logic is simple, subtract the id values found in filteredDf from id values found in hugeDF leaving ID values which are not in filterDF,

I marked the subtracted values as column 'd1' just for clarity purpose and then join hugeDF table on the d1 values and dropping d1 to give final result.